# Subtotal Discount not Applying to Multiple Shipping Addresses

Tags: shipping, ce-1.8.1.0, address, discount, multishipping

I'm trying to implement a coupon code subtotal discount (10% off over $150) but it is not applying when shipping to multiple addresses.

For example, I can place an order totaling $200. Adding the coupon code brings the subtotal to $180 in the shopping cart.

However if I click "Checkout with Multiple Addresses" and send products totalling $100 to one location and the rest to another, the subtotal at checkout jumps back to $200. It seems like its treating each shipment as a separate billing transaction.

I can't find a configuration setting or conditional statement to accommodate multiple shipping addresses.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

In Magento multi-address checkout you are correct, each shipping address is a different order. You can see this played out when you step through the multi-address checkout as it will actually take multiple payments.  There is no easy way around this, you are into fairly large modifications to get it to apply the discount across all the items.